# Problems with an UNION MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, union

I have this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS invoice_count, IFNULL(SUM(qa_invoices.invoice_total), 0)
AS invoice_total, IFNULL(SUM(qa_invoices.invoice_discount) ,0) AS invoice_discount
FROM qa_invoices
WHERE (DATE(qa_invoices.invoice_date) BETWEEN '12/06/25' AND '12/06/25') 
AND qa_invoices.status_code IN (5, 8)

UNION 

SELECT IFNULL(SUM(qa_returns.client_credit), 0) 
FROM qa_returns 
WHERE (DATE(qa_returns.returnlog_date) BETWEEN '12/06/25' AND '12/06/25');
```

I get the error:

```
The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns.
```

I'm trying to join this 2 selects with an UNION command, if we look `returnlog_date` and `invoice_date` have the same data condition, if there is any way to perform both queries into one would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a subselect:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS invoice_count,
    IFNULL(SUM(invoice_total), 0) AS invoice_total,
    IFNULL(SUM(invoice_discount), 0) AS invoice_discount,
    (
        SELECT IFNULL(SUM(qa_returns.client_credit), 0)
        FROM qa_returns
        WHERE qa_returns.returnlog_date >= '2012-06-25'
        AND qa_returns.returnlog_date < '2012-06-26'
    ) AS client_credit
FROM qa_invoices
WHERE invoice_date >= '2012-06-25'
AND invoice_date < '2012-06-26'
AND status_code IN (5, 8)
```

Comment: @JohnNuñez: Your suggested edit will prevent usage of an index range scan for the WHERE clause, which could potentially make the query slower. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: I had no idea that they prevent the use of an index would be affect the optimization of the query, please ignore my suggestion thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The error is telling you exactly what the problem is, for a `UNION` you have to have the same number of columns in each query.

I am not sure which column in your second query corresponds to your first query, but you can insert a zero in your second query.

Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS invoice_count
    , IFNULL(SUM(qa_invoices.invoice_total), 0)  AS invoice_total
    , IFNULL(SUM(qa_invoices.invoice_discount) ,0) AS invoice_discount
FROM qa_invoices 
WHERE (DATE(qa_invoices.invoice_date) BETWEEN '12/06/25' AND '12/06/25') 
    AND qa_invoices.status_code IN (5, 8)

UNION 

SELECT 0
    , IFNULL(SUM(qa_returns.client_credit), 0) 
    , 0
FROM qa_returns 
WHERE (DATE(qa_returns.returnlog_date) BETWEEN '12/06/25' AND '12/06/25');
```

Answer (score 1):

Result set you union together have to have the exact same columns.

Answer (score 1):

Well in order to do a UNION u need to have same number of columns